# Sum of multiple invoices amount converted to a currency

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, currency

I'm using PostgreSQL with a table schema that allows payments in different currencies like EUR or USD. I have also a table with the conversion rate of every currency to USD.

I would like to make a sum of every payment amount converted to USD grouped by month/year. What is the recommended way to do it?

My tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE invoice
(
  invoice_id serial,
  ...
  amount numeric,
  currency_type_id text,
  created_date timestamp without time zone,
);

CREATE TABLE currency_rates
(
  code_from text,
  code_to text,
  rate numeric,
);
```

My actual query that just sums the values grouped by month:

```
select extract(month from created_date) as mon, 
extract(year from created_date) as yyyy,
sum(amount) as "Sales" 
from invoice 
group by 1,2 
order by 2,1
```

Comment: please post your attempt

Comment: Do you have a USD->USD=1 record? Can you rely on every currency used having an entry in the conversion table or should you check and do something in case of absence?

Comment: I believe we are going to have USD->USD = 1.0 but I think it will be better to have a query prepared to handle that missing record!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `join` to the lookup table to get conversion rates for currencies other than USD.

```
select extract(month from created_date) as mon, 
extract(year from created_date) as yyyy, 
sum(case when c.code_from <> 'USD' then amount * c.rate else amount end) as "Sales" 
from invoice i
join currency_rates c on i.currency_type_id = c.code_from
where c.code_to = 'USD'
group by 1,2 
order by 2,1
```